# What is a "representation of a registered trade mark[,] together with the registered particulars of that trade mark"?

Tags: trademark

What exactly does the embolded phrase below mean??? Are there examples of such representations?

Please demystify  it in simple English. Pretend I am an average naive 17 y.o. who does not know the law.

I am not a linguist, but I added a comma to separate that adverbial(?)  subordinate clause (starting with "**together with**"), because sentence 46(2) is too long!

[Cap. 559 Trade Marks Ordinance ─ Section 46 Amendment of application](https://www.elegislation.gov.hk/hk/cap559!en)

> 46. 
>
> Amendment of application
>
> (1)
>
> At the request of the applicant, the Registrar may amend an application for registration of a trade mark as provided in this section.
>
> (2)
>
> The Registrar may amend an application for registration of a trade mark **to add a representation of a registered trade mark[,] together with the registered particulars of that trade mark the Registrar considers appropriate.**
>
> (Replaced 3 of 2020 s. 10)

Comment: Your edit has made this question unnecessarily confusing, and your original version was perfectly adequate IMO. You may wish considering changing it back.

Comment: This page from the government of Australia discusses the **representation** of a trade mark: [10.3. Representation of the Trade Mark - General](https://manuals.ipaustralia.gov.au/trademark/3.-representation-of-the-trade-mark---general). If this is a question about grammar, please ask on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) or [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 1):

A representation of a trademark is a term that generalizes a picture of it, to include trademarks that have some different medium such as 3D, color, smell, sound, etc.

The registered particulars of the mark would be a description in words setting forth what is and is not claimed within a mark. For example, often a mark will claim words as they appear in a stylized fashion but not the individual words themselves without the stylized script.

From the comments, Australia [gives the simple example of](https://manuals.ipaustralia.gov.au/trademark/3.-representation-of-the-trade-mark---general):

> The representation of the trade mark may consist of a written
> description of sounds if the sign is not a musical-type sound. For
> example the graphical representation of the trade mark might be the
> words “CLIP, CLOP, MOO” and a concise and accurate description of the
> trade mark might be along the lines “The trade mark consists of the
> sound of a cow taking two steps on pavement, followed by the sound of
> a cow mooing as recorded on the compact disc accompanying the
> application form”.